# Assigning a typcasted int pointer to a typcasted pointer address in C?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I don't know if I even asked the question correctly, but I've been struggling to wrap my head around the following lines of code and wasn't able to find an answer that I could understand.

```
#define GPIO_LED  ((uint32_t *)0x510000A0)

*(GPIO_LED ) = (uint32_t *)num;
```

where num is an integer (between 0 and 255)

Comment: The second line should be `*(GPIO_LED) = (uint32_t)num;`  , the extra `*` is a mistake.  (Depending on details of the compiler and platform, the code might happen to behave the same way with or without the star, but the correct version is no star).

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Let me just point out, per comments below, that this is apparently from working code as is, with the cast being to `uint32_t*`.  This is in fact a rather subtle error on the part of the original programmer.

Answer (score -1):

Okay. `((uint32_t *)0x510000A0)` is a constant of type pointer to `uint32_t` -- in other words, an explicitly declared absolute address.

`*(GPIO_LED ) = (uint32_t *)num;` typecasts the *value* in num into a pointer to `uint32_t`, and then assigns it *at the location* with the absolute addtress `0x510000A0`.

The effect is it's putting the value `num` into the program's memory space at address `0x510000A0`.

This sort of trick is often used in low-level programming to put settings into a memory address that's mapped to some physical device control.

**update**

Yeah, yeah, I got lost in the asterisks. `uint32_t` pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So to be clear, is the asterisks in the typecast for num most likely a mistake?

Comment: Likely, but not necessarily. The type of `*(GPIO_LED )` is `uint32_t`so it's referring to the `uint32_t` value *at the location* `0x510000A0`. The usual thing (and what I think it means from the hint that the name is `num` and not something like `ptr`) would be that you're putting the number into that absolute location.

Comment: It is, however, *possible* that the programmer *meant* `num` to be treated as an address. It wouldn't pass lint, I suspect you'd get a compile-time warning, but at least in C I think it would compile. Bow, I think the programmer should be beaten if so. Of such mistakes are really hairy subtle bugs made.

Comment: In the code I grabbed this from, num is declared as a uint32_t and not a pointer (and will only range from 0 to 255). Since this is the case, will the C compiler most likely ignore the asterisk? I assume this is the case since the program successfully compiled and functioned as expected.

Comment: If num had been treated as an address, the program would not have functioned as expected

Comment: If it's been treated as an address by the compiler, you might be right. But what if the register at `0x510000A0` implements an API that asks for the *address* of an object in memory? Bits is bits, and a programmer might imagine that because it's an address it has to be a pointer type.

Comment: @njduescher by golly, you have observed, in the wild, exactly the error for which I suggested the programmer should be beaten. Remember, at the machine level, bits is bits: a pointer that has the value `0x12345678` has exactly the same value as a `uint32_t` with the value `0x12345678`. The compiler will assign it, the machine won't know any better. Until some poor programmer comes along and asks "Why are they casting that to a pointer?"

Comment: So it's not that it ignores the `*`, it's that whether its `uint32_t` or `uint32_t*`, `0x000000FE == 0x000000FE`.